Complex derivative and differentiability
I have a question regarding complex derivatives. Our professor said that a complex function $f(z)$ has a derivative at point $z_0$ if there exists a finite limit of $\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$ as $z\rightarrow z_0$, and also that $f(z)$ is differentiable at point $z_0$ if $f'(z)$ is continuous at point $z_0$.How does this differ from when we learned real analysis? There we said that function is differentiable at point if it has derivative at that point. Why would we involve continuity now? Also we showed using C.R. equations that $f(z)=zRe(z)$ is differentiable only at point 0. How could then it's derivative be continuous if it exists only at one point?

If your prof said that existence of $f’$ at one point $z_0$ implies $f’$ is continuous at $z_0$, then they are wrong.
But the sentence you wrote

$f(z)$ is differentiable at point $z_0$ if $f'(z)$ is continuous at point $z_0$

is trivially true. Of course if $f’$ is continuous at $z_0$, then $f$ is differentiable at $z_0$ (this is also true in real analsis, and is completely trivial… if not the function $f’$ doesn’t even make sense).
A non-trivial correct statement would be that if $U\subset\Bbb{C}$ is open and $f:U\to\Bbb{C}$ is complex-differentiable at each point of $U$, then the derivative $f’:U\to\Bbb{C}$ is a continuous function (actually it is also differentiable, and so $f$ is infinitely often differentiable… actually even better, about every point $f$ has a locally convergent power series expansion). This is one of the nice theorems of complex analysis, and is not true over $\Bbb{R}$.

Thanks for your answer. The function from last paragraph would then be called analytic (holomorphic). Is this correct? Also what would you say about $zRe(z)$? Is it differentiable at 0 or it just has derivative at 0? Its derivative should be also equal to 0 btw.

@baja1997 I would rather call $f$ holomorphic on $U$, and then say as a theorem that $f$ is holomorphic on $U$ if and only if $f$ is (complex-)analytic on $U$ (meaning locally admits a convergent power series expansion).  But some books (e.g Ahlfors) use the term analytic, but in my opinion it is way too early to introduce that term. Regarding $f(z)=z\text{Re}(z)$, any of the following is fine: (1) “$f$ is (complex-)differentiable at the origin” or (2) ”$f$ has a (complex-) derivative at the origin”. It is of course real-differentiable everywhere.

Thanks a lot. This is what I needed to know.
